# Pass shared dataset parameter to expression?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got following items:

- A SSRS report with input parameter called `ALLOWED_ITEMS` - this parameter is a text with ids separated with `;`, like `1;2;3;4;6`
- Shared dataset with parameter called `ALLOWED_ITEMS`
- Stored procedure that's called inside dataset through `Query type: text`

I pass `report.ALLOWED_ITEMS` to `dataset.ALLOWED_ITEMS` and it works fine, however I have to split those values into separate values before passing to associated stored procedure. I wanted to use expression to do so, however I don't know how to get `dataset.ALLOWED_ITEMS` value inside expression.

tl;dr: How to get value of shared dataset's parameter inside shared dataset's query generated in expression?

Something like that:

```
="select [some column] from [some_table] where [some_id_column] in (" & split(getSharedDataSetParameterValue('ALLOWED_ITEMS'))
```

Comment: You don;t need to split the semi colon separated string before passing it to the SP. you can split it in the query using a string split function

Comment: @Mazhar Yes, this is a solution that we'll use if there's no way to do it in expression before passing to sql.

Comment: but why would you want to do that?  What business purpose with that serve?

Comment: @Mazhar We don't want our report SPs to parse parameters that's why we want to use expression for that.